# How can I deal with reinforcement learning problem when terminating some episodes early

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Episodes during reinforcement learning have a fixed length. However, because of physics, some episodes are terminated yearly because flying agent hit the ground. In my situation the terminal state is defined as flying agent reaching point A on the ground. However, each episode has time limit (if flying agent didn't reach point A in some specified time then the flight was unsuccessful). Occasionally flying agent hits the ground before reaching point A and this also implies unsuccessful flight. While both situations may be explicitly expressed as negative reward I wonder 1) if it makes sense to keep fixed length episodes and penalize agent for "flying" underground; 2) have time as part of state?

Comment: As I understand in mountaincar environment max time is 200 iterations and time is not part of state. It looks like that the difference in my case is hitting the ground early.

Comment: "Episodes during reinforcement learning have a fixed length." this is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, I found that this is not necessary, i.e. mountaincar. However, I am not sure how to handle cases when terminal state is not reached - in our case flying agent hit the ground.